# What is the summation in this equation?

Tags: summation

$$\frac {\sum_{i=1}^N  (x_i-u)/N}{p^4}$$

Is it only top part of the fraction including the N or just whatever is in the parenthesis. I'm making a code that includes this equation and I need to put it in a loop so that is why I am asking. Also pretend the p and u are numbers they already declares I just did not know how to put it on here so they are placeholders.

Comment: That's poor notation, but I'd guess it means $\cfrac {\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N  (x_i-u)}{p^4} = \cfrac {\frac{1}{N}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N  x_i\right)-u}{p^4}\,$.

Comment: Yea sorry about that it was given to me like that so I didnt know if N was part of the summation equation.